# Selector for border?

Tags: css

I have a div with a large border and I wanted to animate it so that it rotates when you click on the border, but not the actual thing.
This is the html: `<div id="sidebar"></div>` and the CSS

```
#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius:180px;
    background-color: white  #85edb5 white white  ;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 150px;
    border-color: white  #85edb5 white white  ;
}
```

I want it to rotate by 90 degrees when the '#85edb5' part is clicked on, but I don't know how to animate a border. Is there a certain selector for a div's border?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rotate only the border when the the user clicks the inside and rotate everything when the user clicks the border you can achieve this with css.

Example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lrscto8/

HTML:

```
<div class="border">
    <div class="innerBorder">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.border{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;

    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* WebKit */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* Opera */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* Standard */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.border:active{ /* When the border is clicked */
     /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    /* WebKit */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    /* Standard */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.innerBorder{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: crosshair;
    z-index: 2;

    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* WebKit */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* Opera */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* Standard */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.innerBorder:active{ /* When the inner part is clicked */
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* WebKit */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Standard */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```